Test Runner authentication window appears for 2 seconds and disappears
I work with Azure DevOps Version Dev17.M153.5
I created a test plan and then created test suites and test cases inside.
I install Test Runner desktop client
When I try to run my test suite (test case) the Test Runner (Azure Test Plan) authentication window appears for 2 seconds and disappears
I followed the recommendations below:
cleared my browser cache and cookies
allowed pop-ups for the Azure DevOps site.
But it does not work.
How do i get test runner to work?
I would really appreciate your help

Hi, welcome to Stack overflow. Are you using the Azure DevOps Server 2019? Because your version is Dev17, I checked from the TFS version mapping.  Have you tried to reinstall the Test Runner desktop client? You can find the download link in the step 2 from Run tests for desktop apps. The note in it: Currently, the Test Runner client is available only for x64.

According to Azure DevOps Version Dev17.M153.5, it seems that you are using the Azure DevOps Server 2019.
You can try to reinstall the Test Runner desktop client. You can find the download link in the step 2 from Run tests for desktop apps. The note in it:

Currently, the Test Runner client is available only for x64.

I installed the version 17.153.32407.5 (AzureDevOps2019.Update1.2) to test the issue and it works in my test.
